# How to Attach a String to a Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a Javascript variable `var test="hello"` I want to add the prefix "world" to the variable's string within a function so that test="worldhello". How do I write that command in JavaScript code?

Comment: just: `test = "world" + test;`

Comment: jcoat, buddy... you gotta try stuff out once in a while.  This question is way too trivial to post here.  You wouldn't ask how to add 1 and 1 with javascript; this is basically the same thing.

Comment: [This took two seconds via a google search](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String concatenation:
`test = "world"+test`

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "hello";
var newStr = "world" + test;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "hello";
test = test + " world";
```

or

```
var world = " world";
var test = "hello" + world;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var var2 = "world";
test = "hello "+var2;
```

in a function

```
function concatenate(str,con){ 
        return str.toString()+con.toString(); //toString() for prevent an int or float sum
 }
var x = concatenate('hello ','world'); //hello world
var y = concatenate(x,"!!!"); //hello world!!!
```

Comment: fwiw a concat function already exists in javascript.  "hello".concat("world" will return "helloworld")

Comment: I don't knew that function, thank you for having written